# How do I Share a Public Folder with Windows Users?

Tags: windows, samba

I am new to Ubuntu, I would like to share a folder to my Windows machines on my LAN but the whole permissions thing is a bit of a mystery.   Should I share the Public folder contained within my Home Folder byt right clicking on it and using the share option?

Thanks!

Noob

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes, that is a good way to share the folder.  It will prompt you for permissions much like windows - whether to allow others read-only access, or write access.

Linux permissions apply to the owner, the group, and/or the general public.  Generally, the group permissions are not that important for normal use.  Each of these has 3 permissions that are used in combination: read, write, execute.  So if you are owner, you might have read/write permissions, but others might have only read, or even none.